# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcollada14dom21.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, collada

I have hit this error at the linker stage:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot
> open file 'libcollada14dom21.lib'

I dunno why, libcollada14dom21.lib is in VSDIR/VC/lib.

Comment: Then use your brain what is supposed to be.

Comment: I mean VSDIR as "C:\Program Files\...", a little fantasie... :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you add libcollada14dom21.lib to Project Options -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Comment: It is in additional dependencies list. Do I have to put in to other list?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, solved :) The libs were in the lib dir, not in the lib/amd64 :D

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this in solution where there are multiple projects. Even though all outputs are created to the same folder, I still had to provide a relative path of the library `Project settings >>...>> Linker >> Input >> 'Additional Dependencies'` from the client project or include hardcoded path of where to find the library!

Another craziness is that it also seems to depends on relative path of output of client executable. If my output directory is standard, the relative path doesn't work! If I change output directory to the same folder where the library is then relative path from executable works...kind of strange.